# In Next.js v12 it's possible to set a page to use the Edge Runtime for SSR? How?

Tags: next.js, vercel, edge-runtime

I'm using v12.3.4

I noticed that the page router version of this doc [Rendering > Edge and Node.js Runtimes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/edge-and-nodejs-runtimes), don't explain how to do it, [the app router version](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/edge-and-nodejs-runtimes) instruct to set `export const runtime = 'edge'` on the page.

I try that, but in Vercel it renders the page with type "Serverless function" instead of "Edge function".

[image]